# jre 1.6 with GWT

Tags: gwt, java

I have an application written in GWT 1.4 I am all set to up grade it to GWT 1.7/2.0 Before starting i just want to confirm that GWT 1.7.1 above versions supports jre 1.6??

Comment: If you're going to be upgrading anyway, why not go straight to GWT 2.0?

Comment: Yes definitely.. Thanks Cletus.

Answer (score 2):

From [version 1.5 of GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html) you can now use the Java 5.0 (JDK 1.5) language constructs as well, e.g. generics, enums. This means that you have a much greater chance of sharing code between the client and server sides of your application, if the server-side is written in Java.

The [JRE Emulation Library](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) of GWT supports more methods and has been updated with generics support. But it is still not a complete implementation of the JRE standard library, e.g. no BigDecimal, no file support, etc.

Having said all of that, I am not sure exactly what you mean by "supports jre 1.6"?

Comment: Actually my application makes use of some API's written in an application which will soon be using JDK 1.6(earlier it was using JDK 1.5) As i am new to java and GWT am not sure whether up grading it to GWT 2.0 will cause any incompatibility issues??

Comment: This should help you decide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294402/gwt-application-up-grade-from-1-4-to-2-0 PS: I'm agree with others - you should go straight to 2.0.

Comment: GWT 2.0 (and 1.7) both run on JDK 1.6 for hosted/development mode. When you compile the code to JavaScript with the GWT compiler, some JDK 1.6 API method calls may fail because they are not implemented in the JRE Emulation Library.

Comment: Thanks David, Igor.. Feeling much more comfortable with GWT, JDK..

To sum up it means that i can create a project in GWT 2.0 (with the same naming structure as my original app) and can import the code from repository. I will get some warnings due to depracated functions which i can opt to remove or not. And then can use the 2.0 features!!!

Answer (score 1):

GWT. 2.0 requires 1.5 or later.  Refer to http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html

I have been running with 1.6 for a while now with no issue.